# Use function of namespace A in function of namespace B

Tags: php, namespaces

I have a script A, placed in namespace A. In this script, I wrapped all of the functions defined inside it in a class A.

Then I have another script B, placed in namespace B, also with all of the functions of the script wrapped into a class B.

The class B contains 10 functions, whereas only one function B_1 of them needs access to a function defined in class A. Hence, I decided to place the `require script_A` statement inside that function B_1.

Problem is: I want to use a function A_1 of class A in namespace A inside that function B_1 of class B, defined in namespace B. When I do this inside function B_1:

```
require "script_A.php";
use namespace_A\class_A;
```

My syntax corrector tells me `unexpected use of "use"`. The only way my `require script_A` inside function B_1 with subsequential use of function A_1 seems to be possible is by invoking A_1 using a fully qualified namespace:

```
require "script_A.php";
\namespace_A\class_A::A_1();
```

I just wanted to double-check if that's usual? Is it really not possible to use "use" to import namespaces inside PHP functions of other namespaces ? Or am I misunderstanding sth? Full code example of script B:

```
namespace B;

class B {
  
  public static function B1() {

    require_once "script_A.php";
    use A\classA;

  }

}
```

My linter reports an error on the `use` here. My alternative was the code below, which works:

```
namespace B;

class B {
  
  public static function B1() {

    require_once "script_A.php";
    \A\classA::A1();

  }

}
```

Comment: `require "script_A";` <-- quotes missing?

Comment: Where are you using "use..."? In the global scope? Can you post your full source code?

Comment: example added in edits, nope the quotes are not the problem, simply forgot them, sry.

Comment: See my answer below, `use` cannot be used inside a block (method / function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope):

> **Scoping rules for importing**
> The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be block scoped.

The following example will show an illegal use of the use keyword:

```php
<?php
namespace Languages;

function toGreenlandic()
{
    use Languages\Danish; // <-- this is wrong!!!

    // ...
}
?>
```

This is where `use` should be put - in the global space:

```php
<?php
namespace Languages;
use Languages\Danish; // <-- this is correct!

function toGreenlandic()
{
    // ...
}
?>
```

Comment: oops, damn man I somehow oversaw that part.. Thank you! So the best solution if I want to require the file in the function is to trigger A_1 via the fully qualified name, I guess? Or is the file required anyway at compilation time, no matter if I use the function B_1 or not, if I place the require inside B_1?

Comment: You can keep the `require` statement inside your B1 method (it is run at runtime and you should only require it when you need it). Only the `use` must be put in the global space. `use` declaration is just an alias and it does not have to be after the needed script is loaded.

Comment: And by putting the use declaration in the global scope (best practice: right after the namespace declaration), you should be able to use the alias, the fully qualified name is not needed.

Comment: Well but this wouldn't work right? I mean, use ```use``` inside the global scope, at the top of the file, which is only conditionally ```required``` inside B1? How do you think about the approach of using the fully qualified name inside the function B1 (copied above)?

Comment: It will work fine with `use namespaceA\classA` after the namespace declaration, `require "scriptA"` in the method body and simply using the `classA` alias; Just try it out.

Comment: You could define aliases even if you do not have the namespaces or classes for real. Try it out: `use A\B\C\D;`. It will not throw any errors.

Comment: That's crazy; didn't know that, just feels wrong or insecure to me. Anyway it works, so thanks a lot mate!

Comment: Yes, it might sound strange at first (especially if you come from Java, C# & co.), but this is how namespace aliasing works in PHP. It actually makes sense if you understand the ecosystem.